# How to get rid of vertical spaces around "multicols" environment in "acmart" class?

Tags: multicol

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
First paragraph.

Second paragraph.
\begin{multicols}{2}
First line\\
Second line\\
\columnbreak\par
Third line
\end{multicols}
End of second paragraph.

Third paragraph.
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

[image]

Notice the vertical spacing between the first paragraph and the second - it is pretty small. However, the spacings between `multicols` and the paragraphs before and after it are very large. How to make them similar to the spacing between regular paragraphs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spacing before and after `multicols` is controlled by the length `\multicolsep`, so setting it to 0 (the default value of the spacing between paragraph) makes the spacing consistent with other paragraphs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
First paragraph.

Second paragraph.
\begin{multicols}{2}
First line

Second line
\columnbreak\par
Third line
\end{multicols}
End of second paragraph.

Third paragraph.
\end{document}
```

If you want to use another value for `\parskip`, you can set `\multicolsep` to this value as well, but then the spacing will be doubled after `mutlicols` because a paragraph ends at the end of the environment so both `\parskip` and `\multicolsep` are added. In that case, modifying `multicols` to add at the end a negative spacing of the same length should do the trick.